# CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform for of arbitrarily named config files

Tags: web-config, app-config, web-config-transform

NuGet packages such as `CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform` tranform `web.*.config` or `app.*.config` to `web.*.config.transformed` or `app.*.config.transformed` upon a VS build.

However, what if you have config files of form `{arbitrary-name}.config` ?

For example, `MyAssembly.dll.config` and its transform rulesets `MyAssembly.dll.debug.config` & `MyAssembly.dll.release.config`

`CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform` does not appear to work for these file patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [target source code](https://bitbucket.org/jstangroome/configtransform/src/5ff270723dff/ConfigTransform/CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform.targets) it looks quite simple to modify it to allow any .config file to be transformed. Actually I think that transforming any XML file should be possible.

I will fork that repository tomorrow for and experiment with this.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: In this example I modified CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform.targets directly. But you should create a separate .targets file and reference that in your .csproj.

Add a ConnectionString.config (as an example) and then add the transforms.
[image: Transform files]

Add this to the .targets file (your config name just has to match the regex expression - `(?i)^ConnectionString\.` in this case):

```
<Target Name="TransformAllConnectionStringConfigTransformFiles"
        Condition="'$(WebProjectOutputDir)'!=''"
        BeforeTargets="Compile">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ConnectionStringConfigTransformFile Include="@(None);@(Content)" Condition="'$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(Filename),&quot;(?i)^ConnectionString\.&quot;))' == true and '%(Extension)'=='.config'" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <TransformXml Source="ConnectionString.config" Destination="%(ConnectionStringConfigTransformFile.Identity).transformed" Transform="@(ConnectionStringConfigTransformFile)"
                Condition="'@(ConnectionStringConfigTransformFile)'!=''" />

  <CreateItem Include="%(ConnectionStringConfigTransformFile.Identity).transformed"
              AdditionalMetadata="CopyToOutputDirectory=Always">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Content"/>
  </CreateItem>

</Target>
```

Build, and your .transformed files are created.

[image: .transformed files]